# Is a number sequence increasing or decreasing?

Tags: math, sequence

I'm asking for a non-programming point of view because i want to see the meaning - why is it that way?
There is a sequence in one book and the formula for it is  (2n+3)/(6n-5). And it is said that it is decreasing which can be seen by the obtained formula: -28/((6+1)(6n-5)). I see the formula works for every member but how can i obtain that formula which determines if the sequence is decreasing or increasing?

Comment: Generally speaking, if the numerator (top - `2n` in this case, ignoring the offset) grows slower than the denominator (bottom - `6n` in this case), then the sequence will be decreasing, as in this example. If the numerator grows faster than the denominator, then it will be increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're interested in is the difference between two sequential elements, take for example n and (n+1).

The nth term is (2n+3)/(6n-5)

The (n+1)th term is (2n+5)/(6n+1)

Now, you can find the difference between these two terms:

f(n+1)-f(n) = (2n+5)/(6n+1) - (2n+3)/(6n-5)

Notice that, conceptually, the value is the Difference between one term and the next one.

This simplifies to the expression you wrote.  Now, just to be pedantic, there is a small typo in the solution you gave, but it looks like an actual typo, not a misunderstanding or wrong answer.  You have "(6+1)" where it should be "(6n+1)"

Now, when this value is positive, the sequence is increasing, and when it is negative the sequence is decreasing.  This value, for example, will always be negative for n>5/6.  There is a negative number in the numerator, and no way for the denominator to become negative to cancel it out.

Comment: How can the (n+1)th term be (2n+5)/(6n+1)?? Isn't it (2(n+1)+3)/(6(n+1)-5)?

Comment: Yep, but then you can simplify the expression.  2(n+1)+3 becomes 2n+5 __ 6(n+1)-5 becomes 6n+1

Answer (score 0):

- Go to : http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=c44e503833b64e9f27197a484f4257c0
- Under "derivative of" input your formula : (2*x+3)/(6*x-5)
- Click "submit" button
- Click the "Step-by-step solution" link

OPs question: How to get from (2*x+3)/(6*x-5) to -28/(5-6x)^2
Answer: Find the first derivative of (2*x+3)/(6*x-5)
How: Start with quotient rule for finding derivatives http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule to simplify that you'll need a few other rules http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Differentiation_rules